# How do I customize the searchScore?

Tags: search

In my article listing page, I have a search function. I define the article query like so:

```
{% set orderByRule = 'postDate DESC' %} {# Default order. #}
{% if searchQuery is not null %}
    {% set orderByRule = 'score' %}
{% endif %}

{% set articleEntries = craft.entries()
    .section('articles')
    .search(search|trim)
    .orderBy(orderByRule)
    .relatedTo(categoryQuery)
    .limit(21)
%}
```

The articles have a custom field called `articleBody` instead of the regular `body`.

Now, the `searchScore` I get on each article seems weird to me, because it doesn't seem to care about the body text at all. However I recently realized this is probably because `searchScore` is calculated on title, slug and body, only. In other words, searchScore doesn't care about my `articleBody` field.

In case it matters, my `config/general.php` file has this in terms of customization for the search functionality:

```php
'defaultSearchTermOptions' => [
    'attribute' => 'title',
    'subLeft' => true,
    'subRight' => true,
],
```

I can find very little documentation on the subject in general to be honest. I did find [this article](https://gregorterrill.com/posts/search-scores-in-craft-cms), but it doesn't talk about customizing the parameters with which searchScore is calculated.

So how do I customize what pieces of content searchScore is calculated on? Can it even be done?

Comment: What kind of field is ``articleBody``? Make sure in the field settings that "use this field's values as search keywords" is [ticked](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/searching.html#rebuilding-your-search-indexes). Then rebuild the search index if necessary.

Comment: @RitterKnight It's a Redactor field. It is being used for search keywords, that's not the problem. The problem is that the words within this field isn't receiving a `searchScore`.